# Join array values except a specific one and create new values using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array `$data`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 049-1090
            [color] => color:Beige;Brown|
            [Finish] => Finish:Distressed;Handscraped;Matt|
            [Grade] => Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|
            [Installation Location] => Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|
            [Installation Method] => Installation Method:Nail Down|
            [Specie] => Specie:Maple|
            [Warranty] => Warranty:25 Years|
            [Width] => Width:5 inch|
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 107-1079
            [color] => color:Brown;Yellow|
            [Edge] => Edge:Square Edge|
            [Finish] => Finish:Matt|
            [Grade] => Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|
            [Installation Location] => Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|
            [Installation Method] => Installation Method:Glue Down;Nail Down|
            [Specie] => Specie:Maple|
            [Warranty] => Warranty:25 Years|
            [Width] => Width:3 5/8 inch|
        )
)
```

Now I want to create an array `$final_array` which will contain only 2 keys. First key is `sku` and second key is `feature`. `feature` key will consist of the values of all of the keys other than `sku` so the final array will look like:

```
(
[sku]=>049-1090
[feature]=>color:Beige;Brown|Finish:Distressed;Handscraped;Matt|Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|Installation Method:Nail Down|Specie:Maple|Warranty:25 Years|Width:5 inch
)
```

The `|` character should be eliminated from end.

I have tried like this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($data as $value){

   foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){

            $final_array[] = ['sku'=>$innerkey,'feature'=>$innervalue];

   }

}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Please always present your array data as `var_export ()` generated text -- it makes less work for volunteers who want to provide a working demonstration.  Also, bear in mind when you accept an answer too soon, it may discourage other volunteers from providing a better answer (obviously, it doesn't discourage me personally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should give you the results you want. It iterates over each array in `$data`, then iterates over each of the keys in those arrays, copying the `sku` to the `sku` element in a new array and adding all features to the `feature` element in the new array. Finally the closing `|` is trimmed off the `feature` element before the array is pushed to `$final_array`:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($data as $features) {
    $product = array('feature' => '');
    foreach ($features as $key => $feature) {
        if ($key == 'sku') {
            $product['sku'] = $feature;
        }
        else {
            $product['feature'] .= $feature;
        }
    }
    $product['feature'] = trim($product['feature'], '|');
    $final_array[] = $product;
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Output for your sample data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [feature] => color:Beige;Brown|Finish:Distressed;Handscraped;Matt|Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|Installation Method:Nail Down|Specie:Maple|Warranty:25 Years|Width:5 inch
            [sku] => 049-1090
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [feature] => color:Brown;Yellow|Edge:Square Edge|Finish:Matt|Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|Installation Method:Glue Down;Nail Down|Specie:Maple|Warranty:25 Years|Width:3 5/8 inch
            [sku] => 107-1079
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0UUHY)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner, conditionless approach...

1. Temporarily store the sku value and remove it from each row.
2. Manually declare the sku-keyed element and dynamically declare the remaining values as an imploded and right-side trimmed string.

Concise and easy.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TFHGM))

```
$final_array = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $sku = $row['sku'];
    unset($row['sku']);
    $final_array[] = [
        'sku' => $sku,
        'feature' => rtrim(implode($row), '|')
    ];
}
var_export($final_array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sku' => '049-1090',
    'feature' => 'color:Beige;Brown|Finish:Distressed;Handscraped;Matt|Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|Installation Method:Nail Down|Specie:Maple|Warranty:25 Years|Width:5 inch',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sku' => '107-1079',
    'feature' => 'color:Brown;Yellow|Edge:Square Edge|Finish:Matt|Grade:B (Select/Advantage)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor|Installation Method:Glue Down;Nail Down|Specie:Maple|Warranty:25 Years|Width:3 5/8 inch',
  ),
)
```